# EhCache and Database Refresh

Tags: spring, refresh, ehcache

I am using Spring and ehcache. using a query I populate the data into the Cache, this process has to happen every 10 mins. Is there a configuration to set this??

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I used google. Check this out, this [link](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jackrabbit/sandbox/inactive/orm-persistence/applications/test/ehcache.xml) might be helpful. Also check this [tutorial](http://byteco.de/2010/01/26/integrating-spring-and-ehcache/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, ehCache would be used to give a ttl to invalidate your cache automatically.  From what I can gather from your question, you are asking to automatically refresh the cache every ten minutes.  For that, I would run a scheduled service that evicts and reloads.  For example:

```
@Cachable("Foo")
public Foo getFoo() {
    ...
}

@CacheEvict("Foo")
public void evictFoo(){
    ...
}

@Scheduled(fixedRate = 10L * 60L * 1000L) //Ten minutes
public void automaticCacheRefresh(){
    evictFoo();
    getFoo();
}
```